# SCons problem - dont understand Variables class

Tags: python, variables, scons

I'm working on an SConstruct build file for a project and I'm trying to update from Options to Variables, since Options is being deprecated. I don't understand how to use Variables though. I have 0 python experience which is probably contributing to this.

For example, I have this:

```
opts = Variables()
opts.Add('fcgi',0)
print opts['fcgi']
```

But I get an error:

```
AttributeError: Variables instance has no attribute '__getitem__':
```

Not sure how this is supposed to work

Comment: Note for someone who ends up here totally confused like I was: You *must*  `Add()` variables in order for them to be actually read from the file. You can't just add things to the file and expect them to show up in your `opts`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically you would store the variables in your environment for later testing.

```
opts = Variables()
opts.Add('fcgi',0)
env = Environment(variables=opts, ...)
```

Then later you can test:

```
if env['fcgi'] == 0:
    # do something
```

Answer (score 1):

That specific error tells you that class `Variables` hasn't implemented python's `__getitem__` [interface](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) which would allow you to use `[ ...]` on  `opts`.  If all you want to do is print out your keys, the `Variables` [documentation](http://www.scons.org/doc/1.2.0.d20090113/HTML/scons-api/SCons.Variables.Variables-class.html) seems to indicate that you can iterate over your keys:

```
for key in opts.keys():
    print key
```

Or you can print out the help text:

```
print opts.GenerateHelpText()
```