# SCons configuration file and default values

Tags: python, configuration, scons

I have a project which I build using SCons (and MinGW/gcc depending on the platform). This project depends on several other libraries (lets call them `libfoo` and `libbar`) which can be installed on different places for different users.

Currently, my `SConstruct` file embeds hard-coded path to those libraries (say, something like: `C:\libfoo`).

Now, I'd like to add a configuration option to my `SConstruct` file so that a user who installed `libfoo` at another location (say `C:\custom_path\libfoo`) can do something like:

```
> scons --configure --libfoo-prefix=C:\custom_path\libfoo
```

Or:

```
> scons --configure
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
### Environment configuration ###
Please enter location of 'libfoo' ("C:\libfoo"): C:\custom_path\libfoo
Please enter location of 'libbar' ("C:\libfoo"): C:\custom_path\libbar
### Configuration over ###
```

Once chosen, those configuration options should be written to some file and reread automatically every time `scons` runs.

Does `scons` provide such a mechanism ? How would I achieve this behavior ? I don't exactly master Python so even obvious (but complete) solutions are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SCons has a feature called "[Variables](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/x2429.html#AEN2488)". You can set it up so that it reads from command line argument variables pretty easily. So in your case you would do something like this from the command line:

```
scons LIBFOO=C:\custom_path\libfoo
```

... and the variable would be remembered between runs. So next time you just run `scons` and it uses the previous value of LIBFOO.

In code you use it like so:

```
# read variables from the cache, a user's custom.py file or command line
# arguments
var = Variables(['variables.cache', 'custom.py'], ARGUMENTS)
# add a path variable
var.AddVariables(PathVariable('LIBFOO',
        'where the foo library is installed',
        r'C:\default\libfoo', PathVariable.PathIsDir))

env = Environment(variables=var)
env.Program('test', 'main.c', LIBPATH='$LIBFOO')

# save variables to a file
var.Save('variables.cache', env)
```

If you really wanted to use "--" style options then you could combine the above with the `AddOption` function, but it is more complicated.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456100/scons-problem-dont-understand-variables-class) talks about the issues involved in getting values out of the Variables object without passing them through an Environment.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick ;) Is there another way to get the value of a variable ? Something like `print var.getVariable('LIBFOO')` ?

Comment: @ereOn I've scoured the documentation, but there does *not* seem to be any way to do this. Quite asymmetrical. You have to shove the Variables in an Environment and read it out. I'll update the post if I ever find out though.